# How can I start a Docker container on boot in OS X?

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

How can I configure a Docker container to (reliably) start on boot in OS X Yosemite? I've tried various approaches using LaunchAgents, Kitematic, .bash_profile, etc. but haven't come up with a bulletproof way of ensuring that the following commands run without issue (VirtualBox crashes, race conditions, path/environment issues, etc.):

`/path/to/docker-machine start default`

`eval "$(/path/to/docker-machine env default)"`

`/path/to/docker start server`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try breaking the two steps apart. Start Virtualbox with a LaunchAgent, then delegate starting the container to a [startup script *inside* the docker host](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/host_integration/). This avoids both race conditions and environment issues.

It should solve everything bar Virtualbox crashes, which is probably a whole question to itself.

Comment: You sure the link still works? 
It seems like it is redirected to an updated way of doing things!

Comment: @cyberPrivacy the doc page still looks basically the same to me.